# JQL query to fetch a list of tickets touched by a list of users

Tags: jira, jql

I have a team of 8 members and have a requirement to list the tickets touched by them in the last week . Please help.

```
assignee was in (x,y,z) AND created <=-15d AND updated <= -15d
```

Comment: By "touching tickets" you mean being `assignee` only? Because regarding Jira tickets, there are many activities related to tickets, e.g.: commenting, changing statuses and (many) others.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is what you are looking for.

assignee was in (x,y,z) AND (created <='-15d' AND updated <='-15d')

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is working but quite simple. If someone needs something **more complex  jql query** that **covers different activities** related to the jira issue ticket (*commenting*, *changing status* and *reporting* an issue), you can use this:

```
status changed BY (x,y,z) DURING (startOfDay(-7d), startOfDay()) OR
assignee was in (x,y,z) DURING (startOfDay(-7d), startOfDay()) OR
reporter was in (x,y,z)
```

---

There are some limitations for further options, e.g.:

- history searches do not support the `worklogAuthor` field,
- you have to repeat and expand `issueFunction` piece into several `OR` parts in order to filter by several users in comment section

but if you would not mind them you can expand it even more to cover also *comments* and *worklog*:

```
issueFunction in commented('by x after 2023-01-01') OR
status changed BY (x,y,z) DURING (startOfDay(-7d), startOfDay())  OR
assignee was in (x,y,z) DURING (startOfDay(-7d), startOfDay()) OR
reporter was in (x,y,z) OR
worklogAuthor in (x,y,z)
```

And you could improve it and expand it even more...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what "touched" means, `updatedBy()` might be what you are looking for.

> Search for issues that were updated by a specific user, optionally within the specified time range. An update in this case includes creating an issue, updating any of the issue's fields, creating or deleting a comment, or editing a comment (only the last edit).[2]

So one possibility could be

```
issueKey IN (updatedBy(x), updatedBy(y), updatedBy(z)) DURING (startOfDay(-7d), startOfDay())
```

References:

1. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-find-issues-which-are-updated-by-a-specific-user-using/qaq-p/933031#M373180
2. https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver081/advanced-searching-functions-reference-970611548.html#Advancedsearchingfunctionsreference-approverupdatedBy()